Text composable not updating only in RELEASE build
I've a composable that contains a text composable which displays the a duration string provided in the params of the composable function.
The problem is that the duration string is getting updated with change in value smoothly when I'm installing a debug build but when I install a release build the duration string gets updated till "00:02" and gets stuck at "00:02", after this it does not update anymore.
//this is how I'm calling it
CallStatusInfo(
            modifier = Modifier
                .align(Alignment.Center)
                .padding(vertical = 8.dp),
            callStatus = viewModel.callStatus,
            callDuration = viewModel.callDuration
        )

@OptIn(ExperimentalFoundationApi::class)
@Composable
fun CallStatusInfo(modifier: Modifier = Modifier, callStatus: String, callDuration: String?) {
    Text(
        modifier = modifier.basicMarquee(),        
        text = when(callStatus){
             "ringing" -> "ringing"
             "connected" -> callDuration ?: ""
            else -> ""
        },
        style = MaterialTheme.typography.body2,
        fontWeight = FontWeight.W600,
        maxLines = 1
    )
}

In order to reproduce this one can create a viewModel by using Hilt and then use this:
Note: The code below is not my exact code but a short version of it.
var callDuration by mutableStateOf<String?>(null)
        private set

var callStatus by mutableStateOf<String>("connected")
        private set
private var startTime = Instant.now()

init {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            while (true) {
                val timeElapsed = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime.toEpochMilli()
                val duration = formatTimeToDuration(timeElapsed)
                callDuration = duration
                delay(1.seconds)
            }
        }
    }

I tried logging inside the composable and found that the parameter value is getting changed every second but the composable is still not updating in release build.
One more strange thing is as soon as I touch or interact with any other component on the screen, the duration starts getting updated.
Would love some help here as I've been stuck with this strange issue for a long time with no results.
EDIT - Tried using this and it works perfectly fine (text composable starts reflecting the changes)
var duration by remember { mutableStateOf("") }
LaunchedEffect(key1 = callDuration) {
    duration = callDuration ?: ""
}

But this is not the right way. I would like to know whats wrong with my composable.

The issue that you're experiencing is that the recomposition of your screen is not happening when you're expecting it.  You can read more about recomposition through Android's official docs, if you're interested.
Long story short, I think you're doing some weird things both in your VM, and your actual Composable when it comes to the information transfer.  For example, the VM seems to be using the mutableStateOf() function, which is generally reserved for Composable functions, rather than classes.  Moreover, your Composable doesn't seem to be consuming the VM's state correctly either, by observing through the composable functions of observeAsState(..).
Why not try to use more generic paradigms for them both?  Here's a quick example of what I mean:
class YourViewModel : ViewModel() {
    var callDuration = MutableLiveData<String?>(null)

    var callStatus = MutableLiveData<String>("connected")
   
    private var startTime = Instant.now()

    init {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            while (true) {
                val timeElapsed = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime.toEpochMilli()
                val duration = formatTimeToDuration(timeElapsed)
                callDuration = duration
                delay(1.seconds)
            }
        }
    }
    ...
}


@OptIn(ExperimentalFoundationApi::class)
@Composable
fun CallStatusInfo(
  modifier: Modifier = Modifier, 
  viewModel: YourViewModel = viewModel()
) {
    val callDuration: String? by viewModel
      .callDuration
      .observeAsState(initial = null)

    val callStatus: String by viewModel
      .callStatus
      .observeAsState(initial = "connected")

    Text(
        modifier = modifier.basicMarquee(),        
        text = when(callStatus) {
             "ringing" -> "ringing"
             "connected" -> callDuration ?: ""
             else -> ""
        },
        style = MaterialTheme.typography.body2,
        fontWeight = FontWeight.W600,
        maxLines = 1
    )
    ...
}

Using this more traditional paradigm, you should rest assure that if anything changes with the LiveData objects inside the View Model class, your Composable should be able to consume them correctly as a state, and therefore, trigger recomposition (whenever it is needed) at due time.

It is perfectly fine to use mutableStateOf in a ViewModel.  Only remember is reserved for Composables. Additionally, LiveData is not the preferred way to use with Jetpack Compose. This is not an actual solution to the question.

It's too bad you see it that way, given that this solution works perfectly fine for me!  Good luck finding another working solution.

@BenjyTec is absolutely correct here, LiveData is long gone. Using states through viewModel has been working perfectly in my project except this particular composable.
